# LinearLayout height in onCreate is 0

Tags: android

I'm trying to dynamically adjust the height of my rows depending on the (screen height - my layout height) / list.size.

Unfortunately in the `onCreate` method the layout height returns null (not so when i call it in an on click listener).

Is there another method I can call it in?

Answer (score 61):

You have to wait until layout happens, which is after `onCreate()`. You can do so by listening to `onSizeChanged()` on a View or by posting a Runnable from `onCreate() (myView.post(new Runnable() { ... }))`.

Comment: There seems to be no listener for onSizeChanged in Android 1.6?
(I even tried with new View().setOnSize...

And findViewById(R.layout.main) returns null...

Seems like i'm an idiot but i don't quite grasp android yet...

Comment: i put it on the button for which size i'm waiting meanwhile..

this.btNext.post(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    // Initialize tableLayout with Contacts
    initTableLayout();
   }
  });

Thanks for the info.

Comment: Why does posting a `Runnable` to the `View` guarantee that the code within the `Runnable` will be executed after layout has happened? Is it a design feature of `View` that messages are processed out of is `Handler` once layout has occurred?

Comment: The UI event queue will process events in order. After setContentView() is invoked, the event queue will contain a message asking for a relayout, so anything you post to the queue will happen after the layout pass.

Comment: 2 lines that are worth more easy than 10 pages of documentation...simple and to-the-point...thnx...

Comment: @RomainGuy I know this post is old, but for future searches, this technique works wonderfully for most devices, but fails on Nexus S (running 2.2, and 4.0).

Comment: I also used to post a Runnable to the View I want to measure, but I have some cases where getting back to a fragment after a back press, the measurement of the view still returns 0. Might be only happening in nested fragments. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: The fact that there is no clear and reliable callback for this purpose is a crime against all Android developers.