# Determining the size of an Android view at runtime

Tags: android, android-view

I am trying to apply an animation to a view in my Android app after my activity is created.  To do this, I need to determine the current size of the view, and then set up an animation to scale from the current size to the new size.  This part must be done at runtime, since the view scales to different sizes depending on input from the user.  My layout is defined in XML.

This seems like an easy task, and there are lots of SO questions regarding this though none which solved my problem, obviously.  So perhaps I am missing something obvious.  I get a handle to my view by:

```
ImageView myView = (ImageView) getWindow().findViewById(R.id.MyViewID);
```

This works fine, but when calling `getWidth()`, `getHeight()`, `getMeasuredWidth()`, `getLayoutParams().width`, etc., they all return 0.  I have also tried manually calling `measure()` on the view followed by a call to `getMeasuredWidth()`, but that has no effect.

I have tried calling these methods and inspecting the object in the debugger in my activity's `onCreate()` and in `onPostCreate()`.  How can I figure out the exact dimensions of this view at runtime?

Comment: Oh, also I should note that the view itself definitely does *not* have 0 width/height.  It appears on the screen just fine.

Comment: Can you post <ImageView ... /> tag from xml layout?

Comment: I struggled with many SO solutions to this problem until I realized that in my case the dimensions of the View matched the physical screen (my app is "immersive" and the View and all of its parents' widths and heights are set to `match_parent`). In this case, a simpler solution that can safely be called even before the View is drawn (e.g., from your Activity's onCreate() method) is just to use Display.getSize(); see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30929599/5025060 for details. I know this isn't what @NikReiman asked for, just leaving a note to those who may be able to use this simpler method.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on @mbaird's advice, I found a workable solution by subclassing the `ImageView` class and overriding `onLayout()`.  I then created an observer interface which my activity implemented and passed a reference to itself to the class, which allowed it to tell the activity when it was actually finished sizing.

I'm not 100% convinced that this is the best solution (hence my not marking this answer as correct just yet), but it does work and according to the documentation is the first time when one can find the actual size of a view.

Comment: Good to know.  If I find anything that would allow you to get around having to subclass the View I'll post it here.  I'm a bit surprised onPostCreate() didn't work.

Comment: Well, I tried this and it seems to work. Just not really the best solution since this method is calles frequently not only once at start. :(

Answer (score 196):

Use the ViewTreeObserver on the View to wait for the first layout. Only after the first layout will getWidth()/getHeight()/getMeasuredWidth()/getMeasuredHeight() work.

```
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = view.getViewTreeObserver();
if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
  viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
      view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
      viewWidth = view.getWidth();
      viewHeight = view.getHeight();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Be careful with this answer as it will be continuously called if the underlying view is a video / surface

Comment: Can you elaborate on that @Kevin? 

Two things, first of all, since it is a listener, I would expect a single callback, and next, as soon as we get the first callback, we remove the listener. Did I miss something?

Comment: For me, it was called every time the video surface was redrawn and not once.

Comment: Before calling any ViewTreeObserver methods its recommended to check isAlive():

    if (view.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive()) {
        view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
    }

Comment: any alternative to `removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);`? because it is deprecated.

Comment: @FarticlePilter, use removeOnGlobalLayoutListener() instead. It's mentioned in the docs.

Comment: @VikramBodicherla `removeOnGlobalLayoutListener()` requires API Level 16.

Comment: It's not ideal but Udi Oshi's solution worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189525/ongloballayoutlistener-deprecation-and-compatibility

Comment: Warning: I used this approach in a fragment, but it is causing a memory leak which I (and other developers with this problem) are struggling to find a solution for.

Comment: @ban-geoengineering can you give us more details? Maybe a link to a SO question.

Comment: @Vikram Bodicherla See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28264139/view-getviewtreeobserver-addongloballayoutlistener-leaks-fragment

Comment: Good to know what would really help though is some leak analysis. What's holding the fragment up?

Comment: For me after rotation, calling getMeasuredWidth() and getMeasuredHeight() of View return 0 inside onGlobalLayoutListener

Comment: Check my answer to see a better solution based on ktx: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57496626/3461631

Answer (score 83):

There are actually multiple solutions, depending on the scenario:

1. The safe method, will work just before drawing the view, after the layout phase has finished:

> ```
> public static void runJustBeforeBeingDrawn(final View view, final Runnable runnable) {
>     final OnPreDrawListener preDrawListener = new OnPreDrawListener() {
>         @Override
>         public boolean onPreDraw() {
>             view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
>             runnable.run();
>             return true;
>         }
>     };
>     view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(preDrawListener); 
> }
> ```

Sample usage:

```
    ViewUtil.runJustBeforeBeingDrawn(yourView, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Here you can safely get the view size (use "getWidth" and "getHeight"), and do whatever you wish with it
        }
    });
```

2. On some cases, it's enough to measure the size of the view manually:

> ```
> view.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
> int width=view.getMeasuredWidth(); 
> int height=view.getMeasuredHeight();
> ```

If you know the size of the container:

```
    val widthMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(maxWidth, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST)
    val heightMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(maxHeight, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST)
    view.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
    val width=view.measuredWidth
    val height=view.measuredHeight
```

3. if you have a custom view that you've extended, you can get its size on the "onMeasure" method, but I think it works well only on some cases :

> ```
> protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
>     final int newHeight= MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
>     final int newWidth= MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
>     super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
> }
> ```

4. If you write in Kotlin, you can use the next function, which behind the scenes works exactly like `runJustBeforeBeingDrawn` that I've written:

   ```
    view.doOnPreDraw { actionToBeTriggered() }
   ```

Note that you need to add this to gradle (found via [**here**](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/introducing-android-ktx-even-sweeter.html)) :

```
android {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:#.#'
```

Comment: Seems that solution #1 will not always work with `OnPreDrawListener`. Tested case when you want to run code from Activity's `onCreate()` and you immediately background app. Easy to repeat especially on slower device. If you replace `OnPreDrawListener` with `OnGlobalLayoutListener` - you won't see same issue.

Comment: @questioner I don't understand, but I'm happy it helped you in the end.

Comment: Though I usually use `ViewTreeObserver` or `post`, in my case number 2 helped (`view.measure`).

Comment: @CoolMind You can also use a new method, in case you use Kotlin. Updated answer to include it too.

Comment: why does kotlin have additional functions for this? google are crazy, this language is useless (just should stay with java), it's much older than swift but only swift got enough popularity https://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/ (swift 12 position and kotlin 38)

Comment: @user924 "why does kotlin have additional functions for this?" -  It's not in Kotlin framework. It's in an extra library that you are free to use. If you don't use it, it doesn't make the app smaller or larger, if you can always use Proguard.

Comment: @user924 "values could be incorrect, so don't use solution #2" - that's why I wrote "in some cases". It depends on what you do.

Comment: @user924 "why do you put some weird runnable in the first solution?" - as a convenience, and to avoid bugs. Also, BTW, speaking of bugs, you forgot to remove the listener, as I did. That's one reason to use it instead.

Comment: @user924 OK. I think in Kotlin it doesn't matter much, because of function-inline. So even if you use the shortened version, behind the scenes it will become the larger version, without any Runnable. Just as in the case of using `Math.max` , instead of the full condition.

Comment: @user924 Kotlin can be used on PC, as far as I remember. And even if it's not, you can put the logic in Kotlin, and still access it via Java.

Comment: @user25 On #1 , just like all operations on UI views, you will have it run on the UI thread anyway, in both the caller and then in on onPreDraw. No need for handler.

Comment: @user25 If there won't be a call to "run", nothing will occur.

Comment: @user25 Show me the exact issue, in a sample project. To me it worked in all cases.

Comment: @user25 "run" makes perfect sense. You pass the logic you want to do when you are ready to get the size of the view. You can't pass a function reference on Java, like on some languages. Instead you pass something that can run, like a Runnable. It is meant to be used multiple times, in various places in your app.

Comment: @user25 How is it related? Runnable is not a thread. It will run on the UI thread, as you are supposed to do. You are supposed to do UI operations on the UI thread.

Comment: @user25 You can't pass "method" to the function "runJustBeforeBeingDrawn" . You can pass only instances of a class.

Comment: @user25 Which is why it's perfectly fit to put it here. A thread isn't related to here. A runnable is the best thing. You just put the code in it , as you are promised to be able to get the size of the view there. Threads have nothing to do with here. It's just a Runnable.

Comment: @androiddeveloper I'm sorry I understood, it's meant to be as parameter, I just don't use it in different class

Comment: @androiddeveloper for me it didn't work sometimes when I got back from another activity

Comment: @user25 I've updated my answer to show you how to use it. Maybe now you will understand the logic of it. It's besically the same as what Google offers for Kotlin.

Comment: @user25 It depends on how you use it, of course. It's a one time usage.

Comment: @androiddeveloper no I understood how it works, so we can use it to get callback from another class (util class for example), I actually don't use such tricks, but now mb I'll try sometime

Answer (score 24):

Are you calling `getWidth()` before the view is actually laid out on the screen?

> A common mistake made by new Android developers is to use  the width
>   and height of a view inside its constructor. When  a view’s
>   constructor is called, Android doesn’t know yet how  big the view will
>   be, so the sizes are set to zero. The real sizes are calculated during
>   the layout stage, which occurs after construction but before anything
>   is drawn. You can use the `onSizeChanged()` method to be notified of
>   the values when they are known, or you can use the `getWidth()` and
>   `getHeight()` methods later, such as in the `onDraw()` method.

Comment: So does that mean I need to override ImageView just to catch the `onSizeChange()` event to know the real size?  That seems like a bit of overkill... though at this point I'm desperate just to get the code working, so it's worth a shot.

Comment: I was thinking more of like waiting till your onCreate() has finished in your Activity.

Comment: As mentioned, I tried putting this code in `onPostCreate()` which gets run after the view is completely created and started.

Comment: Where is the quoted text from?

Comment: very smart answer (no..).., override all used views (create customs) and use `onSizeChanged()`, are you serious?

Comment: this quote for custom view, don't post it for such answer when we ask about view size in general

Answer (score 10):

Here is the code for getting the layout via overriding a view if API < 11 (API 11 includes the View.OnLayoutChangedListener feature):

```
public class CustomListView extends ListView
{
    private OnLayoutChangedListener layoutChangedListener;

    public CustomListView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        if (layoutChangedListener != null)
        {
            layoutChangedListener.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        }
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
    }

    public void setLayoutChangedListener(
        OnLayoutChangedListener layoutChangedListener)
    {
        this.layoutChangedListener = layoutChangedListener;
    }
}
public interface OnLayoutChangedListener
{
    void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602026/linearlayout-height-in-oncreate-is-0). You can use the `View`'s [post()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)) method.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me in my `onClickListener`:

```
yourView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {               
    @Override
    public void run() {         
        yourView.invalidate();
        System.out.println("Height yourView: " + yourView.getHeight());
        System.out.println("Width yourView: " + yourView.getWidth());               
    }
}, 1);
```

Comment: You don't need to postDelayed when it's in a click listener. You can't click anything until the views have all measured themselves and appeared on screen. Thus they will already been measured by the time you're able to click them.

Comment: This code is wrong. Post delay does not guarantee in next tick your view is measured.

Comment: I would recommend not to go for postDelayed(). It's not likely to happen but what if your view is not measured within 1 second and you call this runnable to get view width/height. It would still result 0. Edit: Oh and btw that 1 is in milliseconds, so it would fail for sure.

Answer (score 5):

Use below code, it is give the size of view.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
       super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
       Log.e("WIDTH",""+view.getWidth());
       Log.e("HEIGHT",""+view.getHeight());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was also lost around `getMeasuredWidth()` and `getMeasuredHeight()` `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` for a long time.......... later i found that getting the view's width and height in `onSizeChanged()` is the best way to do this........ you can dynamically get your CURRENT width and CURRENT height of your view by overriding the `onSizeChanged(`) method.

might wanna take a look at this which has an elaborate code snippet.
New Blog Post: how to get width and height dimensions of a customView (extends View) in Android http://syedrakibalhasan.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-get-width-and-height-dimensions.html

Answer (score 1):

You can get both Position and Dimension of the view on screen

```
 val viewTreeObserver: ViewTreeObserver = videoView.viewTreeObserver;

if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive) {
    viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            //Remove Listener
            videoView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

            //View Dimentions
            viewWidth = videoView.width;
            viewHeight = videoView.height;

            //View Location
            val point = IntArray(2)
            videoView.post {
                videoView.getLocationOnScreen(point) // or getLocationInWindow(point)
                viewPositionX = point[0]
                viewPositionY = point[1]
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After researching, for my linearlayout (but it should work for all views, too.), I first use measure with parameters of ***(0, 0)*** then I read from measured Height or Width then it works well.

```
llayout.measure(0, 0)// after this call, measured Height or Width is not 0 anymore
mychartView.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, llayout.measuredHeight)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know the dimensions of a View right after it is drawn you can simply call post() on that given View and send there a Runnable that executes whatever you need.
It is a better solution than ViewTreeObserver and globalLayout since it gets called repeatedly not just once.
This Runnsble will execute only once and you will know the views size.

Answer (score -1):

In Kotlin file, change accordingly

```
 Handler().postDelayed({

           Your Code

        }, 1)
```

Answer (score -2):

works perfekt for me:

```
 protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        CTEditor ctEdit = Element as CTEditor;
        if (ctEdit == null) return;           
        if (e.PropertyName == "Text")
        {
            double xHeight = Element.Height;
            double aHaight = Control.Height;
            double height;                
            Control.Measure(LayoutParams.MatchParent,LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            height = Control.MeasuredHeight;
            height = xHeight / aHaight * height;
            if (Element.HeightRequest != height)
                Element.HeightRequest = height;
        }
    }
```