# How do you get the width and height of a surface view

Tags: android

I am developing a game.I have drawn images on a surface view which is residing in a relative layout.I want that my game's look and feel should be the same in all resolutions. 
         So now i want to measure the surfaceview/canva's width and height so that I can launch the images in proper proportion rather than hard coded values. But I am unable to retrieve the height and width so please help me.

```
  I tried canvas.getWidth() and all but it returns 0.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to do something like this:

[Determining the size of an Android view at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779173/determining-the-size-of-an-android-view-at-runtime/4000476#4000476)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it is because you try to get the width too soon.

Try this:

```
canvas.post(new Runnable()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        int w = canvas.getWidth();
      }
    }
);
```

Comment: This is more than likely correct, I've had the same problem in the past.

Comment: I saved surface view's width and height in Surface view's overridden method   OnSurfaceViewChanged();  and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Sorry to ask (maybe stupid) questions but I can't find the OnSurfaceViewChanged Method:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html