# Get information from a remoteView?

Tags: android, remoteview

I am been trying to figure out how to get information from a remoteView.
There sees to be plenty of set functions but no get functions.

More precisely I would like to get the size of my remote view 
 [like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779173/determining-the-size-of-an-android-view-at-runtime)  but for remoteViews.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible, sorry. `RemoteViews` is a data structure, designed to be passed to and used by another process.

> More precisely I would like to get the size of my remote view like this question but for remoteViews.

`RemoteViews` does not have a "size", at least in terms of pixels, any more than a `String` does. The resulting widget tree created by the other process applying the `RemoteViews` has a size, but only the other process knows about that.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that. Maybe for the next Android release:-)