# AdMob how to determine when SMART_BANNER size has been allocated

Tags: android, admob

I have an Activity with a layout that includes an `AdView` with `ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"`.  This sits at the bottom of the screen, below a custom `WebView`.  Now, the `WebView` has content that is rendered based on the space (pixel dimensions) available to it.  So before I render the `WebView` content I need to know what size (height in particular) the `SMART_BANNER` will be taking up, and what is therefore left for the `WebView`.  From [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner#smart_banners) it is stated that the smart banner can have a height that is any one of `32dp`, `50dp` and `90dp`.

So far as I can understand, I need to wait for the format of the `AdView` to be decided before I can render the `WebView`.  How can I do that?  Maybe by [setting an AdListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView.html#setAdListener(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener))?  However, the [methods](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener) of `AdListener` only seem to allow me to determine e.g. when an ad has been loaded... I don't want to have to wait for the ad to be loaded, I only want to wait for the actual size of the ad to be allocated.

I know I can avoid all this by setting the `AdView` to `BANNER`, with a fixed height of `50dp`, and this does indeed work fine.  But I would prefer `SMART_BANNER` mainly because the height can shrink to `32dp` in landscape mode on a small phone screen, leaving more room for actual content.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`AdView` has no API to retrieve its size before the Ad has actually loaded and the class is `final`, so you cannot implement it yourself either.

To determine the banner height dynamically you need to use an `AdListener` as you suspected.

Another alternative is to use static values (from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner#smart_banners)) chosen dynamically according to the screen height of the device:

> **32 dp** where height ≤ 400 dp
>
> **50 dp** where height > 400 dp and ≤ 720 dp
>
> **90 dp** where height > 720 dp

(you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4744499/3363481) answer for determining the screen height and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42108115/3363481) for converting between px and dp values)

For example you could use something like this in your `Activity`:

```
private int getSmartBannerHeightDp() {
    DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float screenHeightDp = dm.heightPixels / dm.density;

    return screenHeightDp > 720 ? 90 : screenHeightDp > 400 ? 50 : 32;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, very helpful.  I found that the `onAdLoaded()` method of `AdListener` is a good hook to use.  If I wait for that and render the custom `WebView` from there, it all works nicely.  In particular, it doesn't appear to have to wait until the ad is fully loaded, but seems to fire when the view opens to it's intended size... I haven't done any detailed analysis of the timings, but the overall flow appears to be good enough for my purposes.