# Android: create 4 buttons with equal width in a row (relative layout)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I need to create 4 buttons with equal width in a row. I know how to do that using linear layout and weights, but that's not quite acceptable for me. I have some other views that are related to my 4 buttons, so I'd like to do everything inside relative layout. Is it possible?

Comment: Put your buttons in a `LinearLayout` and put the `LinearLayout` in the `RelativeLayout`. Or do you mean you have views which must be relative to a specific `Button`?

Comment: @MisterSquonk yes, views are relative to a specific Button. Actually, I can put a LinearLayout inside the RelativeLayout, and then just wrap each Button with it's own RelativeLayout, but it's rather weird solution and sounds like "layoutCeption" :)

Comment: Maybe you should add more detail about the entire layout. Then we can offer more complete suggestions. Trying to make buttons be the same length without a LinearLayout is asking for trouble.

Comment: @YuriyPogrebnyak : As you786 says, if you can expand your question to explain what the other views are and how they need to relate to each button then it would possibly help get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about setting the buttons' width to a standard size?

```
<Button
    android:width="75dp"
    ... />
```

**Addition**

To find the width of the display at runtime:

```
int width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() / 4; 
// Set this width to your buttons
```

Comment: The problem is that total screen width is specific to each android device

Answer (score 0):

choose one of the views that will tell the others to have the same width and height . in order to fetch the size of a view , use something like this:

```
private static void runJustBeforeBeingDrawn(final View view, final Runnable runnable)
{
    final ViewTreeObserver vto = view.getViewTreeObserver();
    final OnPreDrawListener preDrawListener = new OnPreDrawListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw()
        {
            Log.d(App.APPLICATION_TAG, CLASS_TAG + "onpredraw");
            runnable.run();
            final ViewTreeObserver vto = view.getViewTreeObserver();
            vto.removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            return true;
        }
    };
    vto.addOnPreDrawListener(preDrawListener);
}
```

Alternative to runJustBeforeBeingDrawn: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28136027/878126

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but I think that the only way you can do this, without **weight** tags, is to runtime/programatically setup it. I've done this by setting a constant in a **integer.xml**, like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="numberOfButtons">4</integer>
</resources>
```

And, in your Adapter/Activity class, something like the following:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
// dm holds your structure of resolution
context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

int width = dm.getWidth();
btn1.setWidth(width/getInteger(R.integer.numberOfButtons));
btn2.seTwidth(width/getInteger(R.integer.numberOfButtons));
btn3.seTwidth(width/getInteger(R.integer.numberOfButtons));
btn4.seTwidth(width/getInteger(R.integer.numberOfButtons));
```

Hope this helps you in some way.

Comment: As stated before by Yuriy, each androidian device has its own resolution/screensize. This value can be obtained with "DisplayMetrics" class.