# Make Listview to Occupy Whole Screen

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have listview that i want to fill the whole screen,There are four items in listview. It leaves empty space below after four items are filled.You can see in the screenshot. It leaves the blank space. I want whole screen to be covered.

[image]

I would like to have like this:

[image]

Here is the source Code

MainActivity.java.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView resultPane;
    List<Taskinfo> list;
    CustomAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        resultPane = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
        list = new ArrayList<Taskinfo>();
        Resources res = getResources(); // resource handle
        Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.browse_home);

        list.add(new Taskinfo("Browse", drawable));
        drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.jewelry);
        list.add(new Taskinfo("Whats New", drawable));
        drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.show);
        list.add(new Taskinfo("Upcoming Show", drawable));
        drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.contact);
        list.add(new Taskinfo("Contact Us", drawable));

        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, list);
        resultPane.setAdapter(adapter);



    }

}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<Taskinfo> list;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<Taskinfo> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;

    }

    public View getView(int index, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_list_item, parent, false);
        }

        Taskinfo t = list.get(index);

        RelativeLayout l = (RelativeLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.testrelative);

        l.setBackgroundDrawable(t.getImage());

        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        textView.setText(t.getName());

        return view;
    }

}
```

single_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/testrelative"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/browse_home"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <!-- ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"

        android:padding="3dip" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45sp"
        android:id="@+id/llayout"
        android:background="@drawable/navbar"
        android:padding="3sp" >



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Golden Stone"

            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" >
        </TextView>


    </LinearLayout>


   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/llayout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: as far as i know, you need to set the height of the views inside the list to fit the screen, and this will be done through code

Comment: if so, use linearlayout and let it fit the whole screen

Comment: thanks @MoshErsan it worked. I used code to dynamically allocate height according to screen size.

Answer (score 2):

Using `ListView` in such case is strange and unnecessary. Think about your constraints (like: what if items overflow?) and just use a proper layout manager. Like a vertical `LinearLayout` with the last item having a non-zero layout weight.

`ListView`s make sense only if you need an abstraction that generates list items on-the-fly.

Comment: I have this problem at the moment. Client want it that way so i have to implement that way. Would you describe it further your suggestion?

Comment: @TonyChhabada: You are not making sense. Your problems stems from the fact that you are trying to do something that `LinearLayout` does perfectly (possibly wrapped into ScrollView), but for some strange reason insist on doing exactly the same thing but with some crazy `ListView` combination.

Comment: @TonyChhabada: ignore all adapters, listviews and stuff. Just make a linear layout, inflate your single_row four times, put proper drawables in and add to the layout. When you add the last one, set some layout weight. Done.

Comment: Thanks @fdreger for you precious time but MoshErsan suggestions helped, I have dynamically allocated height of each item based on screen size to fit on screen

Comment: @TonyChhabada: If I recall correctly, MoshErsan suggested using a LinearLayout, just as I did. Well, do what you want, it's your code, you can keep it as strange as you fancy.

Comment: as far as i know, you need to set the height of the views inside the list to fit the screen, and this will be done through code

Comment: @TonyChhabada LinearLayot allows you to say something like: "share the free space among the item 1 and 2" or "give all the free space to item 4". ListView does not. This is why I suggested using LinearLayout. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to set a background on the ListView. Currently your view should be going to the bottom, but the background of the ListView is transparent, so setting it white should achieve what you're asking.

```
<ListView ...
    android:background="@android:color/white"
... />
```

Comment: no adding background as white won't work.It just starts new item. You can check it here http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/1822/device20130509011734.png

Comment: It doesn't start a new list item - but it does prevent the list from appearing to end before it should. But since you seem to want your 4 items to be evenly distributed, take fdreger's advice and use a LinearLayout with weights.

Answer (score 0):

if there are so few items, you can use the LinearLayout instead, and give weights for each of its items.

However, do note that android supports many devices and screens, so you might want to have a limitation of how small each row would be.

anyway, in case you wish to make each row the fitting height, you can check its size and then divide by the number of items.

in order to get the size of the listView , you can use [this small snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10923514/878126) i've made .