# GridView Adapter single selection mode

Tags: android, gridview

i have one `Fragment` in that i defined one `GridView`,so iam attaching listener for the `LinearLayout` from GridView Adapter so i click the `LinearLayout` of the Adapter it should change the background color of selected layout..

Comment: what is your issue ?

Comment: i have one Booking fragment that contain 4 supporate morning,afternoon,evening fragments containing supporate gridview if i click the gridview items among 4 fragments it should change the colour of that item background and if i click other item previous item colour should be disabled donno which solution is best for this...please help me where i have attach listener either in fragment or adapter so i want small snippets

Comment: ohk i will give you wait. first you add  onitemclick in your fragment

Comment: k but how to change backgroung colour of that item??

Comment: see sloution i will post my solution.it can be help you.if that can be help then give +1

Answer (score 1):

First in your girdview adapter class take on variable exp.

```
int selected;
```

then make on method in grid view like that

```
public void selectedPosition(int postion) 
{
    selected = postion;
}
```

then you can also put a code in getview method of gridview. Like this

```
 if(position==selected)
 {
     imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
 }
 else
 {
     imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#578FFF"));
 }
```

now in onitemclick of grid view you can post like that

```
adapter.selectcrop(position);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

here is a solution example I will give you step by step i think you can solve your problem using that.

Comment: how will you check position==selected condition in getView method??

Comment: just copy that code and paste it .its working i can use that code

Comment: u have textview in getview method ?

Comment: ya but all textview is turned to green before clicking.

Comment: than you can give +1 and accept my answer and dont forgot to remove your answer

Comment: give upper vote my answer 0 to 1 and right tick mark .see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38430856/devide-square-into-four-clickable-triangles/38482147#38482147 to accpect answer