# Device TabGroup's Tab height in pixels depended from device screen size

Tags: android, height, pixel

I need to get height of my tab(shown in the picture) in pixels in my app. 
I need some information that will help me to know what is height of Tab depended from the screen size. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance[image]

Tell the truth I don't need Tab's size in code, I think that each device with same size will have same Tab height, so I want to know what part of screen will take my Tab ,

e.g. I have device with 1080 X 720 pixels , my Tab will take 1/10 part , it means that Tab's height will be 108 pixels

Comment: Have u tried any of these solutions : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779173/determining-the-size-of-an-android-view-at-runtime

Comment: I need some information that will help me to know what is height of Tab depended from the screen size

Answer (score 0):

What I meant to say in my comment earlier was that there are many popular solutions here to get the height and width of any android view.
I have tested this code right now and it is working fine. Try this:

```
final RelativeLayout topLayout  = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.topRelLayout);
        ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = topLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
        if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
          viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                if(Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) >= 16)
                topLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                else
                topLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
             int  viewWidth = tabs.getWidth();
              int viewHeight = tabs.getHeight();

              Toast.makeText(HomeScreenActivity.this, "height = "  + viewHeight + " width = " + viewWidth , 2000).show();
            }
          });
        }
```

Where topRelLayout is the id of root layout of your xml file and tabs is the reference to your tab view.

Even following simple code is working fine too.

```
tabs.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int w = tabs.getMeasuredWidth();
                int h = tabs.getMeasuredHeight();
                Toast.makeText(HomeScreenActivity.this, "height = "  + h + " width = " + w , 2000).show();
            }
        });
```

Using either of the solutions you can get the height/width of any view in any screen size.

EDIT :

After reading your edited question I assume that you need what percentage of the screen has been occupied by Tab widget.
Only solution I know can be implemented is :

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
         final   Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

            tabs.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int h = tabs.getMeasuredHeight();
                    int screenHeight = 0;
                    if(Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) >= 13)
                    {
                        Point point = new Point();
                     display.getSize(point);
                     screenHeight = point.y;
                    }
                    else
                        screenHeight = display.getHeight();
                    double tabPart = (((double)h/(double)screenHeight) * 100); 
                    Toast.makeText(HomeScreenActivity.this, "height = "  + screenHeight + " tabPart = " + tabPart  + " %", 2000).show();


                }
            });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I have edit my question , can you check it?