# Layout dimensions still return 0 even after onCreate()

Tags: android, android-layout

I understand that I cannot get the dimensions too early before the UI has been set up.

I know I have to get the dimensions after the onCreate().

But even if I do the following, they still always return me 0.

**onCreate():**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_path);
        ...
        onCreateDone = true;
    }
```

**I hope to get the dimensions in onSensorChanged()**

```
    // called when sensor values change
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) { // is roughly called 350 times in 1s

        if (layoutSizeNotObtained && onCreateDone) { // only runs once to get the layout size
            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_show_path_relativelayout);
            int layoutWidth = relativeLayout.getWidth();
            int layoutHeight = relativeLayout.getHeight();
            Log.d("ShowPathActivity", "layout size: " + layoutWidth + " " + layoutHeight);

            Constant.setInitialX(layoutWidth / 2);
            Constant.setInitialY(layoutHeight / 2);
            layoutSizeNotObtained = false;
        }

        ....
    }
```

**Where goes wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that there's no warranty, that layout is done during `onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)` call. Views are measured only during first layout and it's done some time after `onCreate()`, but not during it or immediately after.

I would suggest to use [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6569243/657487) via [ViewTreeObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html).

Comment: Where should I add the snippet? I added it into the constructor of my custom view. I saw the method keeps being called. I wish it to be called only once.

Comment: You can call it from onCreate() of your custom view. It called every layout, but You can call removeGlobalOnLayoutListener() so it won't be called further.

Comment: I am really a newbie to this. Here is my custom view. I didn't see onCreate(). Where should I put it? http://pastie.org/private/70tuepnuj59ajtbtesgkg

Comment: Meant onCreate() of the activity, the one provided in Your question.

Comment: Awesome! it works now. I have marked this as the answer. Could you please roughly tell me what the snippet does? It would be nice for the future programmers too. :D

Comment: 'A view tree observer is used to register listeners that can be notified of global changes in the view tree', basically, I think all explanations provided in referenced question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the setContentView function in onCreate? If not, you need to.