# Scaling animation on an already scaled view

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm animating an `ImageView` using the following scale animations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="2.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="2.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="1000" />

    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="2.0"
        android:toXScale="0.0"
        android:fromYScale="2.0"
        android:toYScale="0.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="1000"
        android:duration="1000" />

    <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toDegrees="360" android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="3"
        android:duration="800" android:startOffset="0" />
</set>
```

But the problem is that the `ImageView` is already scaled by the layout, when the first animation begins. This leads to a noticeable jump in size, when the first animation sets the scale to 1.0 .

Is there any way of telling the animation that it should start from the actual size of a view in the layout? 
I also tried working with percentages, which produced the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way using xml, so I ended up using this approach to determine the size at runtime and set up the animation in Java:

[Determining the size of an Android view at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779173/determining-the-size-of-an-android-view-at-runtime)

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand from your query is that you wanna make your animation smoother, by avoiding the obviously noticeable scale animation at the beginning. I think minimizing the 'from scale' in the first scale would help you avoid the jump, maybe something like this would help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<scale
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXScale="0.5"
    android:fromYScale="0.5"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />
<scale
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="1000"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />

<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="800"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="3"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
```

Sorry to keep you waiting; try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<scale
    android:duration="400"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="20%"
    android:pivotY="20%"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toXScale="1.1"
    android:toYScale="1.1" />
```

Comment: No, what I am trying to accomplish is to have the scaling animation start not from a fixed value (neither 0.5 nor 1.0), but from the actual scaling value of the ImageView. This is neccessary, since I dont know to what size the View will be sized on a given device.

Comment: Thank you, but I think you misunderstood the question. My problem is that the ImageView can have any scale at the beginning. Starting from a fixed scale will produce a noticable jump in the animation, no matter what I set it to.