# Subclassing RelativeLayout | How/Where to get its size inside the class?

Tags: android, size, android-relativelayout

Suppose you wanted to create a subclass of RelativeLayout and inside the class definition you wanted to get its width and height. (The subclass is added via xml to the application, match_parent, match_parent).

I've tried following code, but it toasts me 0:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    Toast.makeText(context, "" + this.getWidth(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And this gives me -1:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    Toast.makeText(context, "" + this.getLayoutParams().width, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

So what are my options, or `onMeasure()` only works for subclasses of anroid.view.View?

EDIT: I know I can call `onWindowFocusChanged()` in the `Activity`, but can I get the size of the `RelativeLayout` subclass in its class definition, so that I don't need to couple the two classes just because of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override [onLayout method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/widget/RelativeLayout.java#RelativeLayout.onLayout%28boolean%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%29) or onSizeChanged. [Also you can use ViewTreeOserver.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779173/determining-the-size-of-an-android-view-at-runtime) If you want to know results of onMeasure method use `getMeasuredWidth/Height` instead of `getWidth/Height` inside onMeasure.

Comment: added some more info )