# Where in the lifecycle of my Android app should I get width and height of image view?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-lifecycle

```
private void getPicDetails() {

            targetW = img_cow.getWidth();
            targetH = img_cow.getHeight();

            Log.e("targetW: ", "" + targetW);
            Log.e("targetH: ", "" + targetH); 
        }
```

I have an image view and the method above gets the height and width to print the values of height and width. Now when I call `getPicDetails()` in onCreate, the values are 0, same as when I put it in `OnStart` and `onResume`.

My question is: where should I put my method such that the imageview is initialized and exists?

Comment: have u set the image to an ImageView..?

Comment: Could you please post the code which instantiates img_cow, assuming it is ImageView

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android get width returns 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/android-get-width-returns-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can call inside the **onWindowFocusChanged**

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
    int width=imageView.getWidth();
    int height=imageView.getHeight();
}
```

Comment: what if you need to use it in a fragment?

Answer (score 0):

> where in the lifecycle of my android app should i get width and height
>   of image view

After layout is complete:

```
@Override
public void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    getPicDetails();
}
```

Comment: eclipse says remove @Override, as if onLayout is not a method of Activity

Comment: how do you create your images?

Comment: call camera using photointent and then convert it into bitmap which i have to scale to size of the imageview (which is the reason i'm asking where to call `getPicDetails()`). then stick the bitmap into imageview, you want the code?

Comment: call it after you inflate your layout

Comment: `onLayout` is a method from the View class, not Activity

Answer (score 0):

you can use the next function i've made:

```
  public static void runJustBeforeBeingDrawn(View view, Runnable runnable)
  {
    ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener preDrawListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener(view, runnable)
    {
      public boolean onPreDraw() {
        ViewUtil.this.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
        runnable.run();
        return true;
      }
    };
    view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(preDrawListener);
  }
```

EDIT: Alternative to runJustBeforeBeingDrawn: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28136027/878126