# google api v2 get width and height

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to get width and height from a map fragment. However methods getWidth and getHeight are deprecated and i dont now how to do in google v2.

I used to do like this way:

```
display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
width = display.getWidth();
height = display.getHeight();
```

Please someone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you're trying to get screen dimensions, maybe you should look at this post:

> if you want the the display dimensions in pixels you can use getSize:
>
> ```
> Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
> Point size = new Point(); 
> display.getSize(size); 
> int width = size.x; 
> int height = size.y;
> ```

See this post for details [How to get screen dimensions as pixels in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions).

Comment: what if you have other views on the screen and you want the dimensions of the mapview only?

Comment: You should be able to do that with a `ViewTreeObserver` like explained in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779173/determining-the-size-of-an-android-view-at-runtime.
The goal is to compute the size at runtime and observe the view you want to get its size.