# Weight inside Scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview

I'm having trouble calculating the `weight` inside of an scroll view on my android app. I want the app's content to resize proportionally to the screen size. How can I calculate the `weight` inside a scroll view?

Here some of my code:

```
  LinearLayout layout_principal = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_items);// is horizontal layout and layout of Scrollview

  LinearLayout layout_titulo_opcion = new LinearLayout(this);
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
          0,
          1f);
  layout_titulo_opcion.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

  LinearLayout layout_titulo_opcion2 = new LinearLayout(this);
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
          0,
          1f);
  layout_titulo_opcion2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);

  layout_principal.addView(layout_titulo_opcion);
  layout_principal.addView(layout_titulo_opcion2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get/set the weight, use this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams mylp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)myLayout.getLayoutParams();
int myWeight = mylp.weight; // get weight
mylp.weight = 4; // set weight
```

To set the weight sum, use this:

```
myLayout.setWeightSum(10);
```

Comment: Thanks but i used this                          
int scrollMainHeight = layout_principal.getWidth();                       i take how reference the width of LinearLayout layout_principal

Comment: getWidth() returns the space a layout is using. Weights are used to evenly distribute available space. e.g. two layouts with even weights will get half the available space each. If LayoutA weight=2 and LayoutB weight=1 then LayoutA will get twice as much space as LayoutB. This will resize proportionally to any screen, which seemed like what you were asking...

Comment: Thanks my friend for your comment

Comment: i have another problem, i can't get the layout width  in the oncreate function

Comment: if you mean the width of the layouts that have weights, that's right. Essentially, they are not determined until they are on the screen. When I need to do this I either do it with a callback function like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779173/determining-the-size-of-an-android-view-at-runtime