# Android: ExpandableListView with percentages

Tags: android, expandablelistview

What I am trying to achieve is rather simple. I want to have a full screen ExpandableListView that has each Group of height deviceHeight/4, and each child's height deviceHeight/8. This list can contain more that 4 groups for example, so it should also be scrollable.

It should look something like:

[image]

What's the best way of doing this? :D

Comment: I guess you could implement custom adapter and in your getGroupView, get the height of the ExpandableListView, divide it by four - and set the result as the height of the view before returning it.  Similarly, in getChildView, divide by 8.

Comment: Yes, but since the list is not yet drawn, it's height is practically 0, so this approach does not work :(

Comment: In that case, you can try extending the ExpandableListView class and at the end of its `onMeasure`  do `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter - this would force the redraw of items - _after_ the measurements of the listview are known.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that works is by doing what is suggested here:
[Determining the size of an Android view at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779173/determining-the-size-of-an-android-view-at-runtime) and then doing `convertView.setMinimumHeight(_listHeight/4);`where listHeight is calculated in the `OnGlobalLayoutListener`.

Although this approach works sound, I was still hoping for an approach where I was suppose to give the GroupView the hight in percentage (25%).