# Rotate ImageView from its bottom right corner in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I want to rotate my image view 45 degree from its bottom right corner please suggest me how to do that

I am trying to add rotation in imageview like this

```
 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/poker_table"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:id="@+id/poker_table"
        android:rotation="45" //this line I added
        />
```

but the above code rotating my image from its center point. So please suggest any solution to rotate image from bottom right corner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the size of the `View`, you can use a pair of xml atttributes to set a pivot point for rotating or scaling a `View`: [android:transformPivotX](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:transformPivotX) and [android:transformPivotY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:transformPivotY)

If we assume the `View` has a size of `100dp` x `100dp`:

```
android:transformPivotX="100dp"
android:transformPivotY="100dp"
```

Other possible units are sp, px, in, mm... but unfortunately `match_parent` will not work, and neither will *100%*.

If you don't know the size of the `View` at compile time, your only option is to set the pivot point programmatically (using [setPivotX()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setPivotX(float)) and [setPivotY()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setPivotY(float))) after [determining its actual size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779173/determining-the-size-of-an-android-view-at-runtime).

Comment: when i rotate my image then my image pixels is disturbing can you please also explain me how i can remove this error

Comment: @HemantPrajapat - I think it's better if you ask a new question about this new issue (ideally with some screenshots since I'm not sure what exactly is wrong with your View). One reason for a new question is that we try to keep questions small: solve one problem at a time, not mentor throughout an entire project. This is good for future readers in a similar situation who search for answers which take them one step further (even if their project is quite different from yours). On the other hand you'll reach more people and so increase your chances of getting good advice for each of your issues.