# How to get size of an image from xml in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I am developing an android application that uses an image and has a constraint layout. The attributes for height and width are set to "wrap-content" meaning they are not fixed. On that image, I am creating a  graph using circles. For that, I should know the exact values of the width and height of the image. How can I get the values of width and height from XML to Java?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3594216/2410641

Comment: Yes thanks, it solved the issue. I was calling getwidth and getheight in OnCreate which was returning 0, so I thought there might be some other possible way for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`getWidth`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getWidth()) and [`getHeight`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getHeight()) to get dimensions of any view (in this case `constraint layout`) at runtime.
But be carful, before using this two methods you have to make sure that the view (`constraint layout`) is already created, otherwise it gonna return 0, witch means you can't call them in `onCreate`.
So the correct way to do it is to wait for the view to  be created then get its size.
Like this :

create this method

```
public static void runJustBeforeBeingDrawn(final View view, final Runnable runnable) {
final OnPreDrawListener preDrawListener = new OnPreDrawListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
        runnable.run();
        return true;
    }
};
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(preDrawListener); 
}
```

Then call it when u need to get the dimensions

```
runJustBeforeBeingDrawn(yourView, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Here you can safely get the view size (use "getWidth" and "getHeight"), and do whatever you wish with it
        }
    });
```

Related to your question :
[View's getWidth() and getHeight() returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/views-getwidth-and-getheight-returns-0)
[Determining the size of an Android view at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779173/determining-the-size-of-an-android-view-at-runtime)

Comment: This solved my issue. I was calling getwidth and getheight in OnCreate which was returning 0, so I thought there might be some other possible way for it.