# Disable smooth resize to make Android app fully compatible with Windows Subsystem for Android

Tags: android, android-view, windows-subsystem-for-android

My app needs to perform some view resizing after the layout is done. It's currently done in `onWindowFocusChanged()`.

It's not working as intended on Windows 11 (using Windows Subsystem for Android, WSA). During manual window resizing, the Activity gets destroyed and recreated a few times, but:

- `onWindowFocusChanged()` is never called during or after the resizing
- the Activity is not recreated at the exact end of the resizing, so [posting a runnable to the UI queue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3602144/774398) is not an option: the view's dimensions would still be wrong at this point.

I have noticed that toggling on the WSA compatibility setting `Disable smooth resize` actually solves the issue: nothing happens *during* the resizing, but `onWindowFocusChanged()` is called when the resizing is over.

[image: Disable smoot resize toggle]

**Can I force this behavior programmatically?**

I don't want users to be forced to change this setting to use the app normally.

Comment: That's not an Android thing, its a windows thing.  So unless you wrote an Android app only to run on Windows (in which case- why did you do that?) there won't be a way because the entire concept doesn't exist on Android.

Comment: I have a pretty similar issue: whenever I manually resize the app window, Activity recreation causes an app crash. I temporary solved it by enabling the other one setting in your screen "Force app to be non-resizeable" but I would avoid it, you know an how-to ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding out that this window resizing issue was not specific to WSA: it also occurs on regular Android devices and emulators when using free-form resizable windows.

The solution is to stop relying on `onWindowFocusChanged()` to be notified of changes of the window size: it's an unreliable hack (see question).

Instead, I now use an `OnGlobalLayoutListener`, like so:

```
       myGlobalParentView.getViewTreeObserver()).addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                setDimensionsOfVariableViews();
            }
        });
```

Game views are correctly resized on every change of window size.
Basic protection (check if size has changed since last call) against excessive resizing/layouts and infinite loops is implemented in `setDimensionsOfVariableViews()`, so we never remove the listener.